# Deleting data securely, which tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a [wiping](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiping) that supposedly fulfills this function, but it's name doesn't strike me as the most adequate, since the first thing I was asking was "wiping what?". I'm thinking there are better terms like `secure-deletion` or `data-deletion`, since they are self-explanatory and actually more discoverable.

Answer (score 3):

“Wiping” is a commonly-used name. The tag name on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) is [`destruction`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/destruction). This may not be the most discoverable name for non-professionals though. We can define synonyms.

Comment: Full ack. We might introduce `secure-deletion` as synonym for those not familiar with the term "wipe". "Destruction" sounds too, hm, destructive ;)